# mysql: how to sum multiplied partials

Tags: mysql, sum, multiplication

Having tables like:

sold_items:

```
code   | size   | quantity 
abc123 | small  | 4
abc123 | medium | 2  
xyz987 | small  | 3
xyz987 | medium | 1
xyz987 | large  | 2
```

price_list:

```
code   | size   | price 
abc123 | small  | 5
abc123 | medium | 7  
abc123 | large  | 9 
xyz987 | small  | 10
xyz987 | medium | 13
xyz987 | large  | 15
```

which would be your best (faster query) approach to get

results:

```
code   | sold_items | cash
abc123 | 6          | 34
xyz987 | 6          | 73
```

Comment: +1 for showing us the table schema, sample data and the expected results. It's been awhile since I saw a question articulated like this :)

Comment: @bonCodigo: appreciated thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
 SELECT si.code, SUM(si.quantity), SUM(si.quantity * pl.price) as cash
 FROM sold_items si
 INNER JOIN price_list pl ON pl.code = si.code AND pl.size = si.size
 GROUP BY si.code
```

Comment: Why the subquery? `GROUP BY si.code` without derived tables would suffice.

Comment: @Eric you are faster by the time I was creating a fiddle to show ;)

Comment: @ypercube - you are right, not sure why I was thinking that subquery was necessary

Comment: Both answers given so far work and they look very similar to me. You both pointed me to the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out please.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb6c/13)

Code:

```
select p.code, sum(p.quantity), sum(q.quantity * p.price)
from prc p
inner join 
qty q
on p.code = q.code
and p.size = q.size
group by p.code
;
```

Results:

```
CODE    SUM(Q.QUANTITY)     SUM(Q.QUANTITY * P.PRICE)
abc123      6                   34
xyz987      6                   73
```

Comment: the left join is only necessary if you join `prc -> qty`.  If you start with the `qty` table and join to `prc` then an inner join will suffice.

Comment: @EricPetroelje True, here either it's a left or inner doesn't make much difference. I took it Because earlier I was infact counting like count(p.code) ;) then I double checked the question and realized OP is asking for Sum of quantity not the count.... That's when I miseed out the left join to inner join.