# SQL Using a group by function for only one column (but selecting more than one column)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok i have the below code

```
SELECT PO_NUMBER, MIN(PO_QUANTITY) AS PO_QUANTITY, SUM(COALESCE(SHIPPED_WT, 0)) AS SHIPPED_WT  
FROM VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
WHERE SYSDATE > PO_SHIPMENT_TO
GROUP BY PO_NUMBER
HAVING MIN(PO_QUANTITY) > SUM(COALESCE(SHIPPED_WT, 0))
```

This does everything i want in terms of grabbing the right data, however i would like to have more columns, something along the lines of

```
SELECT PO_NUMBER, SO_ORIGIN, SO_PRODUCT, SUPPLIER, MIN(PO_QUANTITY) AS PO_QUANTITY, SUM(COALESCE(SHIPPED_WT, 0)) AS SHIPPED_WT, PO_SHIPMENT_FROM, PO_SHIPMENT_TO  
FROM VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
WHERE SYSDATE > PO_SHIPMENT_TO
GROUP BY PO_NUMBER
HAVING MIN(PO_QUANTITY) > SUM(COALESCE(SHIPPED_WT, 0))
```

however i can't group by the other columns, because it will grab data that i do not want.

Any ideas?

I realize a Distinct can be used, but the way i want my data to show, it would eliminate records i would not want to eliminate

PS, i use SQL server, i cannot create/modify a table, all data i use is based on a View, and i cannot alter that either

**EDIT: I provided an answer, however unelegant**

```
PO          PO Qty                  Tracking No        Shipped Qty

PO 1       100                         1                              60            
PO 1       100                         1                              60
PO 1       100                         1                              60
PO 1       100                         2                              15
PO 1       100                         2                              15

PO 2       50                          2                              20    
PO 2       50                          2                              20    
PO 2       50                          3                              30 
PO 2       50                          3                              30



IN the above scenario, totals are

                                PO 1       PO 2

PO Qty                          100         50

Shipped                         75          50          

Unshipped                       25           0         



-          In each PO record, the PO qty is stated in full on each line and therefore is repeated each time the same PO is listed as a record

-          Within a tracking no for the PO, the shipped quantity is stated in full and therefore is repeated each time the same tracking no (for the same PO #) is listed as a record

-          So a tracking number can exist on two different PO’s (as in Tracking no 2 above) in which case the value is counted once for each PO
```

Comment: Here is how an [SQL question can be articulated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203821/mysql-how-to-sum-multiplied-partials) show tables, show sample data, show expected results based on that. You will get a very good answer very quickly from someone in the community and less exhaustive to you and everyone :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT PO_NUMBER, PO_QUANTITY, SHIPPED_WT, PO_SHIPMENT_TO, SO_ORIGIN, SO_PRODUCT, SUPPLIER, PO_QUANTITY-SHIPPED_WT UNSHIPPED 
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PO_NUMBER, PO_QUANTITY, PO_SHIPMENT_TO, SO_ORIGIN, SO_PRODUCT, SUPPLIER,  SUM(NVL(SHIPPED_WT,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY PO_NUMBER) AS SHIPPED_WT 
    FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT PO_NUMBER,  PO_TRACKING_NO, PO_QUANTITY, SHIPPED_WT, PO_SHIPMENT_TO, SO_PRODUCT, SO_ORIGIN, SUPPLIER FROM VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE)) 

WHERE PO_QUANTITY > SHIPPED_WT AND SYSDATE > PO_SHIPMENT_TO
```

After much time, and much hard work, my company could finally allocate a 2nd person to help me (who knew more about sql then i did) to get this thing to work..however putting in modifiers will be tricky and quite annoying..its a bit inefficient

Comment: well not giving us your table schema with sample data and not giving us expected results, it's definitely some sort of best BLIND guessing that we do here.....

Comment: sorry, i was going to post what i just did at the end of the question, but i had a lot to do all at once, than lunch hit (we eat lunch together here)...my fault

Answer (score 0):

How about A JOIN?

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.PO_NUMBER, X.PO_QUANTITY, X.SHIPPED_WT,
Y.SO_ORIGIN, Y.SO_PRODUCT, Y.SUPPLIER, 
Y.PO_SHIPMENT_FROM, Y.PO_SHIPMENT_TO  
FROM (
     SELECT PO_NUMBER, MIN(PO_QUANTITY) AS PO_QUANTITY, 
     SUM(COALESCE(SHIPPED_WT, 0)) AS SHIPPED_WT 
     FROM VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
     WHERE SYSDATE > PO_SHIPMENT_TO
     GROUP BY PO_NUMBER
     HAVING MIN(PO_QUANTITY) > SUM(COALESCE(SHIPPED_WT, 0))) X
     LEFT JOIN VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE Y
     ON X.PO_NUMBER = Y.PO_NUMBER
     ;
```

Following is the demo based on old data...it doesn't have all the rows that you need but it should work by adding other rows as well.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03662/9)

Comment: that gave me 3 more records than the original query, i'll look into it...i have tons of records so it takes a bit

Comment: So for instance, i got a record that has two PO_NUMBER with the same PO_QUANTITY order, and neither has any SHIPPED_WT...but it appeared twice because, for unknown reasons (probably someone entered the data wrong), the two records had different PO_SHIPMENT_TO...with my original query, it would eliminate that 2nd PO_NUMBER (because now it looks like theres an order with double the quantity, which is what i don't want)

Comment: see this is the problem, and why i am struggling with this project....Each order is assigned one PO_NUMBER...however from that order you can assign multiple SO_NUMBER or PICKED_NO...so when they vary, it creates a record for each new PICKED_NO...so i can have 5 records with the same PO_NUMBER, same PO_QUANTITY..so it is double counting the instances i want to grab, so that it can give more information later down the line

Comment: Then you should **normalize** your data perhaps.....instead of putting everything in one table...if you can't do it by creating tables then you may have to do it by creating sub queries...In the first place you shouldn't allow duplicates. However QUANITITY rather does't have `unique` feature alone, that you can't restrict of having same value for multiple records. You should find other means to do so.. And also look into what @BenLin said.

Comment: nevermind, the original query isn't even right anymore...i forgot about one of the aspects, which was if the PO_TRACKING_NO is the same for multiple PO_NUMBER than they should not be counted in the SHIPPED_WT adding function

Comment: AH which I am using in the above `sqlfiddle` there can't be two same tracking number isn't it ;)

Comment: right, but there can be two of the same tracking numbers IF the po_number is different

Comment: back to the ol' drawing board from last night

Comment: If you have multiple tracking no, so_number then you can use the `latest` or `oldest` po_number (order by desc /order by asc) to make sure which po_number record you are picking up...

Comment: right, but if a PO_NUMBER is listed twice, but has two different PO_TRACKING_NO, than it has to pick both up (and add the SHIPPED_WT, and check if its less than the PO_QUANTITY, which if it is, then it will be shown)

Comment: same po number in your table? oh MY! then you have to first run a query checking the `added date` based on sql server or whatever database date/time of the record. Then filter out the distinct based on that... do you know what? can you create your table schema (small sample data) in sqlfiddle then it is much easier to see your issue........

Comment: thanks for all your help, I THINK i got the correct answer now (see above)...but who knows, theres about a million things to look at, something could have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please answer: when you `GROUP BY PO_NUMBER`, are all items in one group have the same `SO_ORIGIN, SO_PRODUCT, SUPPLIER,  PO_SHIPMENT_FROM, PO_SHIPMENT_TO` ? 
If your answer is yes, then you can change the query to:

```
 GROUP BY PO_NUMBER, SO_ORIGIN, SO_PRODUCT, SUPPLIER, PO_SHIPMENT_FROM, PO_SHIPMENT_TO
```

If your answer is no, then your query is logically wrong.

Comment: Well when i add that group by, i get 469 records, as opposed to the 451 from the first query...let me go through it and i'll let you know