# Remove items which don't fulfill all requirement

Tags: sql, sql-except

I have table "OcjeneKorisnika" which consist `Korisnik_ID`, `Artikl_ID` and `Ocjena_ID` fields.
In table I have entry `Korisnik_ID 12` which order articles `Arikl_ID 9` and `Artikl_ID 13` and some values in `Ocjena_ID` for its.

Query below retrieve all `Korisnik_ID`, `Artikle_ID` and `Ocjena_ID` except `Korisnik_ID 12`

```
SELECT Korisnik_ID,
       Artikl_ID,
       Ocjena_ID
FROM OcjeneKorisnika
WHERE (Artikl_ID IN
         (SELECT Artikl_ID
          FROM Kupac_Narudzba
          WHERE (Korisnik_ID = 12))) EXCEPT
  SELECT Korisnik_ID,
         Artikl_ID,
         Ocjena_ID
  FROM OcjeneKorisnika WHERE Korisnik_ID = 12
ORDER BY Korisnik_ID
```

For example `korisnik_ID` 11 have Values in `Ocjena_ID` for `Artikl_ID` 9 and `Artikl_ID` 13 but `Korisnik_ID` 1,`Korisnik_ID` 2, ...  have values only for `Artikl_ID` 9, not for `Artikl_ID` 13 ( in table )

How to show all `Korisnik_ID` which have values in `Ocjena_ID` for both `Artikle_ID` ( 9 and 13 ) and exclude `Korisnik_IDs` which have only values for one `Artikl_ID` ( 9 or 13 ) ?

Sample source data:

```
Korisnik_ID | Artikl_ID | Ocjena_ID 
1  | 9  | 3 
2  | 9  | 4 
2  | 13 | 5 
9  | 9  | 2 
10 | 9  | 3 
10 | 13 | 4 
10 | 15 | 2 
12 | 9  | 3 
12 | 13 | 2
```

I need to have output :

```
Korisnik_ID | Artikl_ID | Ocjena_ID 
2  | 9  | 4 
2  | 13 | 5 
10 | 9  | 3 
10 | 13 | 4
```

Comment: Care enough to update your question with some sample data and expected reults please?

Comment: In table I have :

Korisnik_ID | Artikl_ID | Ocjena_ID
      1     |     9     |    3
      2     |     9     |    4
      2     |     13    |    5
      9     |     9     |    2
     10     |     9     |    3
     10     |     13    |    4
     10     |     15    |    2
     12     |     9     |    3
     12     |     13    |    2

I need to have output :

Korisnik_ID | Artikl_ID | Ocjena_ID
      2     |     9     |    4
      2     |     13    |    5
     10     |     9     |    3
     10     |     13    |    4

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Sorry I have problem to formatting comment above !?

Comment: Very well...........I meant [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203821/mysql-how-to-sum-multiplied-partials) you could update your question...and very sorry for not giving you an example how you should do it...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description doesn't quite seem to match the sample data (from your comment)

This query will return the rows of that have at least both 9 and 13 for `Artikl_ID` (but may have more like `Korisnik_ID` 10 who also has `Artikl_ID` 15).

```
with matches as (
    select Korisnik_ID from OcjeneKorisnika where Artikl_ID in (9,13) 
    group by Korisnik_ID having count(distinct Artikl_ID) = 2
)

select o.* from OcjeneKorisnika o
join matches m on o.Korisnik_ID = m.Korisnik_ID
where o.Artikl_ID in (9,13)
```

Given your sample data the result would be:

```
Korisnik_ID Artikl_ID   Ocjena_ID
----------- ----------- -----------
2           9           4
2           13          5
10          9           3
10          13          4
12          9           3
12          13          2
```

If that is not what you're looking for then you should edit the question and try to clarify what you want.

Comment: Oh my, didn't notice that the question was asked over two years ago... guess the OP is long gone.